# Will Ubuntu run well on this low-spec Lenovo IdeaPad 110-15IRB

Tags: lenovo, hardware

My mom recently bought a new laptop it came with windows 10 and runs like S***. I think it's probably because of windows 10 and all the bloatware shipped with the pc. (really it's packed)

Here are the specs

Intel Celeron n3060
2gb of ram
500gb hdd

I'm hoping to get Ubuntu up an running on it, but wondering if Fedora or Elementary OS might be a better option. Anyway will Linux run well on here? And if so which flavor would you suggest?

Comment: Thanks for your response :) the problem is that another laptop/notebook had a while back also met the requirements but when I installed it, it ran terribly, the sound, wifi, Bluetooth and touch pad drivers did not work at all and despite lots time and effort the was ultimately no fix. Although I believe that was due to the Broadcom chipset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu will definitely run better than windows on your machine. However, I've had issues with it being slow on my old netbook with 1gb of ram, but 2gb should be fine!

If you install Ubuntu and it does run a little slow, you can always find a more light weight flavor (version) of Ubuntu.

Comment: Like Ubuntu netbook edition?

Comment: I apologize for my late reply. I have been preparing for graduation and have had little time otherwise.

A lighter "flavor" of Ubuntu I generally use is Xubuntu or Lubuntu. They use less resources (ram, cpu, etc) thus they tend to run a little better on lower spec machines